# C# XML Documentation Website Link

Tags: c#, xml, hyperlink

Is it possible to include a link to a website in the XML documentation? For example, my method's summarized as

```
///<Summary>
/// This is a math function I found HERE.
///</Summary>
public void SomeMathThing(Double[] doubleArray)
{
   ...
}
```

and when I type

```
SomeMathThing(
```

I want IntelliSense to show the summary with the option to click on "HERE" to link to an outside website. Is this possible? How would it be done?

Comment: This was implemented by this Roslyn issue on GitHub:
[<see> tags in XML docs should be clickable links in the IntelliSense popups.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39139)

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Try:

```
///<Summary>
/// This is a math function I found <see href="http://stackoverflow.com">HERE</see>
///</Summary>
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. It didn't even display "HERE".

Comment: Hmmm, my apologies. I did a little more research (see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/devdocs/thread/8af32a12-bebe-447b-9111-dbe5d970810d) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/82d85250-e5ac-48f2-a787-2ca441904c2c)) -- and it looks like the VS IDE won't display those hyperlinks, but a documentation tool such as SandCastle would be able to display them.

Comment: You can read about Sandcastle [here](http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/01/inline-xml-code-documentation-using-sandcastle/) btw. "Sandcastle, created by Microsoft, is a free tool used for creating MSDN-style documentation from .NET assemblies and their associated XML comment files. It is command-line based and has no GUI front-end, project management features, or an automated build process."   HTH!

Comment: Anyone else having trouble getting this trick to work in CR_Documentor?  It shows up if I use NDoc 1.3 preview style, but not if I use the Sandcastle option.

Comment: Note, there is some variability in support for <see /> as a content tag.
I've found it a bit more consistent when used as a self closed tag just displaying the raw URL. 
(Which is better documentation anyway: as "HERE" is not providing much in the way of explanation.)

Comment: This is not supported by Visual Studio, no Intellisense for `href` attribute.

Comment: For me it wasn't working because my link had an ampersand in the url. Once I changed that to `https://somewhere.com?test1=1&amp;test2=2` it worked.

Comment: This works in VS 16.4.2. Not sure what version it was added, only that you can now click links in the method info window.

Comment: Works in VS 2019, the exact version number is VS 16.6.4. First I tried with "cref", but "href" renders nice. One trick is that  when the tooltip hovers, move your mouse pointer not outside the tooltip and you can click on the link to navigate to the url too. Great stuff VS! 
Does it work in Vs Code too ? Hmmmm..

Comment: Also note it only works in the <summary> tag.  It doesn't work in <remarks> tags (VS 2019 v16.7.6).

Comment: While VS (2019 v16.8) offers no intellisense for the `href` attribute, it does work great in both `summary` and `remarks`, both in `see` and `seealso` tags.

Comment: No anchor tag is created unfortunately

Comment: Make sure your urls are encoded for XML. e.g. 
path/?x=value&y=othervalue 
needs to be 
**path/?x=value&amp;y=othervalue**

Comment: And I am talking about links from inside ///<summary> elements

Answer (score 109):

A bit late on the hype-train, but here is what I found out for Visual Studio 2015.

My sample looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Retrieves information about the specified window. 
    ///     The function also retrieves the value at a specified offset into the extra window memory.
    ///     From <see cref="!:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585(v=vs.85).aspx">this</see> MSDN-Link.
    ///     AHref <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">here</a>.
    ///     see-href <see href="http://stackoverflow.com">here</see>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hwnd"></param>
    /// <param name="index"></param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     Testlink in return: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">here</a>
    /// </returns>
    public static IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hwnd, int index)
    {
        return IntPtr.Size == 4 ? GetWindowLongPtr32(hwnd, index) : GetWindowLongPtr64(hwnd, index);
    }
```

The results are:

1. **Tooltip:**

   - Shows cref-url with !:, but hides "this"
   - Hides ahref-url but shows text
   - Hides seehref url and text
     [image: Screenshot of intellisense tooltip]

---

2. **Object Browser:**

   - Shows cref-url with !:, but hides "this" (not clickable)
   - Hides ahref-url but shows text (not clickable)
   - Hides seehref url and text (not clickable)
     [image: Screenshot of ObjectBrowser]

---

3. **ReSharper** (CTRL+SHIFT+F1, Command ReSharper.ReSharper_QuickDoc)

   - Hides cref-url with !:, but shows "this" (not clickable)
   - Does now interpret ahref-url (Version from 2016 and newer)
   - Hides seehref url and text (not clickable)
     [image: Screenshot of Resharper QuickHelp]

Conclusion: Best one, as Heiner pointed out, would be

```
See <a href="link">this link</a> for more information.
```

**Update**
As Thomas Hagström pointed out, Resharper now Supports clickable a-href URLs. Updated screenshot accordingly.

Comment: Actually, with ReSharper and CTRL+SHIFT+F1 an url is clickable and HTML link is compatible, so that's indeed the best option

Comment: Thanks Thomas Hagström, updated the anwer and screenshot.

Comment: +1 just confirmed that JetBrains Rider (the complete C# IDE from JetBrains with many of the Resharper features) only supports `<a href="...">text</a>` and will NOT display the link or text if you try `<see href="...">text</see>`

Comment: For me, I can use **a, see, and seealso** inside a summary 
```/// <summary>
   ///  Some Txt<br/>
   ///  <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+XML+comments&amp;sca_esv=5fddc3dd36c4976b">a with href</a><br/>
   ///  <see href="https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+XML+comments&amp;sca_esv=5fddc3dd36c4976b">see with href</see><br/>
   ///  <seealso href="https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+XML+comments&amp;sca_esv=5fddc3dd36c4976b">seealso with href</seealso><br/>
   /// </summary>```
**Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.8.6 + JetBrains ReSharper 2023.2.2**

Comment: Note that **seealso** is a bit odd, and probably should not be used generally. i.e. seems was [intended to power a diff section, and supposedly should NOT be used in summary tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947292/661584), but for intellisense it seems it is ignored when NOT in a summary tag. So... prob **best to use <see href=""> or <a href="">**

Comment: **Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.8.6 + JetBrains ReSharper 2023.2.2** (Build 232.0.20230919.80758, ReSharper 2023.2.20230920.162346)

Comment: NOTE: you need to **make sure urls are encoded**... else intellisense and R# don't show anything (invalid XML). e.g. path/?x=value&y=othervalue needs to be **path/?x=value&amp;y=othervalue**

Answer (score 72):

You can use the standard HTML syntax:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">here</a>
```

The text will be displayed in Visual Studio.

Comment: This is the best approach. As the output will still make sense in Visual Studio (it just shows the text) and the link will work in documentation tools like Sandcastle.

Comment: The link becomes clickable in VS 2022. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Only this way works for me in JetBrains Rider 2021.3

Comment: It is the only one that worked for me in Rider 2023.2.3

Answer (score 28):

Use the `<a>` tag. For example, I used this solution in my project:

[image]

Result:

[image]

My XML code:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is C# XML Documentation Website Link
/// <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960426/c-sharp-xml-documentation-website-link">See more</a>
/// </summary>
```

**Or use the `<see>` tag. Result is the same to the `<a>` tag.**

```
/// <summary>
/// This is C# XML Documentation Website Link
/// <see href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960426/c-sharp-xml-documentation-website-link">See more</see>
/// </summary>
```

Answer (score 24):

You can include a !: prefix in a cref to have it passed through untouched in the generated Xml documentation so that tools such as [Innovasys Document! X](http://www.innovasys.com/products/dx2011/overview.aspx) and Sandcastle will use it. e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a math function I found <see cref="!:http://stackoverflow.com">HERE</see>
/// </summary>
```

Visual Studio intellisense won't display that as a link for intellisense though - wouldn't be much point as it's a tooltip so you can't click it anyway.

Comment: There’d be a point if [Object Browser actually made `<see/>` clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20517119/429091) *and* recognized website URIs somehow (since Object Browser is not a tooltip). Just sayin’ ;-).

Comment: This approach is now outdated; it produces code analysis warning [CA1200: Avoid using cref tags with a prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1200). Prefer anchor tags (<a href="...">).

Answer (score 3):

I also tried `<see href="https://some.com/>` first and it did not work; however, I then tried `<seealso href="https://some.url/">` and it *did* work.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
/// <remarks>
/// <![CDATA[ Wireframe link: https://9ljx1q.axshare.com/#id=pinlb0&amp%3Bp=employee_complaint_form&amp%3Bg=1%3B2 ]]>
/// </remarks>
```

where, The `<![CDATA[ and ]]>` tags indicate character data that should not be parsed as XML, allowing you to include special characters without XML parsing issues.

if your Link( URL ) contains special characters like ',', '&', ';', then you have to replace it with HTML Character Entities
Ex. `& => &amp; , ;=> %3B`

Otherwise, if your URL is simple, then `<see href="http://stackoverflow.com">HERE</see>` will work

Note: If you are planning to use a clickable URL, then remember that ASP.NET Core XML documentation doesn't support rendering hyperlinks.

And apart from that, it's better to display your link in a remark section because summary section text is not copyable.