# Adding URL to .NET XML Comments

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to add XML comments to a method, that allows other programmers to follow the URL by clicking on it in the tooltip?

I have tried adding a URL to a method using the following format (I have also tried using the see and see also tags):

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads some data.
/// <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">click me</a>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The id.</param>
/// <returns>Some Data</returns>
private string LoadData(int id)
```

This produces a click-able hyper link to the URL, however this only works when looking at the original source code. If possible I would like to the ability to click and follow the hyper link in the tool tip shown when hovering over a call to the method, rather than the method itself.

Comment: I have seen some suggestions on various forums pointing towards using Microsoft's SandCastle documentation generator.

Comment: If you cannot find a reasonable solution here, you should request this through the Microsoft Connect site.

Comment: This is successfully answered here, 7 years later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960426/c-sharp-xml-documentation-website-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If possible I would like to the ability to click and follow the hyper
>   link in the tool tip shown when hovering over a call to the method,
>   rather than the method itself.

If I understood you question correctly you expect something like shown in the image below
[image]

If yes this your Xml comments are correct and in order to get this put your cursor on the method and Ctrl+Q this is a short for Resharper to get documented help of the method

**Update : Below image is to confirm Ctrl+Q is a ReSharper shortcut**
[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure that Ctrl+Q is not a RS shortcut. At least, it isn't in my installation and I can't really find a corresponding command.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I just suspended ReSharper and tried Ctrl+Q and it does not work

Comment: Could you please be so kind and go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard. Put the cursor in "Press shortcut keys:", press Ctrl+Q and tell me the names that appear in the list "Shortcuts currently used by:". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have uploaded an image with update on my answer, following your steps to check what is set for Ctrl+Q

Comment: Thanks a lot, very much appreciated! :-) I found the command now. However, in my installation it is Ctrl + Shift + F1...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth oh dear are shortcuts are different because my ReSharper Keyboard Scheme is "ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA" and looks like your's must be set to "Visual Studio"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately we don't have ReSharper at my work place and I'm not too sure we will be getting it either. I'll mark this as answered, as I know ReSharper is widely used. But if anyone knows of a way to achieve this, without the use of ReSharper, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, follow the link on '[To insert XML comments for a code element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-xml-documentation-comments?view=vs-2022)'.

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads some data.
/// <see href="http://stackoverflow.com/">click me</see>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The id.</param>
/// <returns>Some Data</returns>
private string LoadData(int id) { return string.Empty; }
```

Comment: This would probably be the accepted answer if the question were posted today - does not require any additional tooling

Answer (score 0):

Without a fancy tool like Resharper, tool tips are not clickable, so there is no way to do this.

However, if the programmer referencing your library were to click on "Go to Definition" for your code, they could expand the comment there and would be able to click on the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this won't work for our team, as quite often we use methods in other DLL's that we don't have the source code for.