# Visual Studio: Can I add links in comment blocks

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm coding software, where I very often need to do graphical illustrations, to explain the behavior of the code, e.g. illustrate geometrically how the shortest distance is found from one of the sides in a triangle to a hit-point in that triangle.

It is getting kind of tedious to use and invent ascii-representations in the comments, so I was thinking if it is possible to embed drawings (pictures created in drawing programs) into the project/solution and link to them in the comment-blocks.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181273/adding-url-to-net-xml-comments. You can embed images as resources

Comment: There's no "URL tag" or "image tag" in the list of markup tags you can use (which are available at [Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx)). Unless you have a tool that knows how to parse it, you won't find it in plain Visual Studio.

Comment: You can create minimal html pages with the images and include their urls. Obviously all files need to be mapped to a common network drive.. Ctrl-Clicking the urls will open the html pages right in VS.

Comment: What do you want the links to do? Where do you want the images to display?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. The pictures even don't need to be included in the project. VS will automatically create a clickable link from any URL placed anywhere in the comment. I recommend you to place the URL inside standard <see> comment tag. Our [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) supports also the <img> tag that will show the picture directly in generated documentation.

Here is the example that uses both ways. In both cases you can click the link directly in the code editor and the picture will show.

```
/// <summary>
/// Click <see href="file:///C:\Pictures\Desert.jpg">here</see> to See the picture.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Here is the embedded picture:
/// <img src="file:///C:\Pictures\Desert.jpg"/>
/// </remarks>
public void Method1() { }
```

Comment: Other links work with Ctl-Click here, images don't work, they only offer to download the imagefile..

Comment: If you don't include the images in the project, how will other team members see the image?

Comment: Also, the `see` tag is used to denote `A reference to a member or field`. In Visual Studio you don't even need that tag, you get a link to the file even if you only type the file://-url. How do you get Visual Studio to show that image in the UI?

Comment: VSdocman or Sandcastle allow to reference also external files in the <see> tag. And you are right, you don't need that tag in the code editor. That's what I wrote in my answer. But once you put the link in the comment, why not put it inside <see> or <img> tag so that other tools can benefit from it?

Comment: Because the see tag is not used for that. The see tag can be verified to point to a specific member or field in the class (which the href does not do). It's like using `<para href="url"></para>`; you *can* do it, but it's not semantically correct. In that case the <img /> is better in my opinion, even though it's not supported as a "standard comment markup".

Comment: And yes, your *tool* can use it, but even then I would argue you shouldn't based on the documentation of the see tag. ;-)

Comment: Even though not specified by MS, <see> is widely used to reference external resources as well. See Sandcastle http://www.ewoodruff.us/xmlcommentsguide/html/983fed56-321c-4daf-af16-e3169b28ffcd.htm or VSdocman http://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/aseelinkxml.htm

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a relative path?

Answer (score 2):

[ImageComments](https://github.com/lukesdm/image-comments) extension for VS 2010/2012 allows images to be displayed amongst code.