# cref doesn't create link in Object Browser

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code in C# 2010 Class Library:

```
/// <summary>
/// Execute all enable tests synchronously.
/// Function may throw exception if executed in invalid state (for example, all tests are disabled).
/// If function doesn't throw exception, this doesn't mean, that all tests succeeded. After function 
/// finished, it is necessary to check the state of all tests.
/// Function is synchronous and may take a long time to execute.
/// Use <see cref="SiX_Dg_RequestStop"/> function to stop this function from another thread.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="AtpException"></exception>
public static void SiX_Dg_Execute()
{
}

public static void SiX_Dg_RequestStop()
{
}
```

When I open this library in Visual C# Express Object Browser, XML comment is shown by this way:

[image: Object Broser]

`exception cref` produces valid link, but `see cref` is shown as plain text, with full namespace added. How can I make this link working?

Comment: Try to fully qualify the method cref. Does that work?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: no, result is still the same.

Comment: And using IntelliSense (delete the content of the cref between the quotes and then press Alt+Enter to re-insert)?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Intellisense shows only XML parameters like `see`, `seealso` etc, but doesn't show available .NET classes.

Comment: It does. You have to press Ctrl + Enter (or was it Alt + Enter?).

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I use Ctrl+Space, any other combination doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Don't know where my head is today ;-)...

Answer (score 1):

I think the object explorer of visual studio does not implement that kind of link. Look at the online documentation of the method "System._AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly"  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example of what you need, then look at the object browser. In the first one there is a link but in the second there is no link.