# How to place arbitrary external url in xml documentation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-documentation

What is the correct way to place arbitrary hyperlink in xml documentation in C# code?

For example, i want to direct the reader to external resource (msdn).

```
/// <param name="textRotation">Text rotation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.alignment(v=office.14).aspx .</param>
```

Url can be placed as normal text surrounded by spaces, and Visual Studio would display it as a hyperlink, but i find it a bit brittle to have it this way.

If you omit the space at the beginning, url would not be parsed as an url, and it would break the markup if you omit the space at the end.

Comment: try it
/// <param name="args">text rotation.<see cref="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.alignment(v=office.14).aspx"></param>

Comment: @Dreamweaver see cref is for referenced code elements, and the question was about external url. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960426/c-sharp-xml-documentation-website-link
check this.