# Clickable hyperlink in IntelliSense tooltip from Obsolete Attribute

Tags: .net, visual-studio, intellisense

**Question:**

Is there a way to add a hyperlink to an [`ObsoleteAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute)'s `message` such that it is clickable in Visual Studio's IntelliSense tooltip?

**Background:**

I know that for XML documentation comments, you can do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960573/2343739):

```cs
public void Main()
{
    MethodWithHyperlinkInXmlDocsIntelliSense();
}

/// <summary>
/// This is a math function I found. <see href="http://stackoverflow.com">HERE</see>
/// </summary>
public void MethodWithHyperlinkInXmlDocsIntelliSense()
{
}
```

[image]

However, neither of the below options show the hyperlink as clickable in Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.3) IntelliSense tooltips.

```cs
[Obsolete("This is a math function I found. <see href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">HERE</see>")]
```

[image]

```cs
[Obsolete("This is a math function I found. See http://stackoverflow.com")]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually**, IntelliSense tooltips for `ObsoleteAttribute` class does not support hyperlink as XML document comments. I have tested it several times.

**So** to help improve this ticket, I reported [the issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1298590/clickable-hyperlink-in-intellisense-tooltip-from-o.html).

You can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention. And I hope the Team will give you a satisfactory reply.

Comment: Thanks. Right, the hyperlink is clickable inline in the attribute declaration. But, I was explicitly asking about clickable hyperlinks in IntelliSense *tooltips*. I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Test with that and get the same behavior as you described. So it is a real question. I have reported it to the DC forum. You can check it. See my updated answer