# Adding comments for a method that links to a markdown file

Tags: c#, markdown, visual-studio-2019

How do I add method documentation where it would link to a markdown file? the mark down file is included in the project solution

was thinking of something like this?

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Click <see href="Notes.md">here</see> to See documentation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="variable1"></param>
        /// <param name="variable2"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string Method() {

           /// insert code here

        }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It looks like live links to http were added to recent VS editions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960426/c-sharp-xml-documentation-website-link). Does what you propose work?

Comment: yeah but those are for site links.. what if you have the markdown file inside the project alraedy, and you want to reference that on the comments?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it would be handy.  I tried a few of the obvious hacks (e.g., using `~` in the "url"), but nothing seems to work.  Put in a feature request

Comment: Did you found anything in the meanwhile?